# TestNg, Maven -Dgroups not filtering Test when group name is more than one

Tags: java, testng, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to execute using command **mvn clean test -Dgroups=group2,smoke**.  It executing all 4 testCases.
But if I use **mvn clean test -Dgroups=group2** it executing Test1 and Test 2 ( as expected).

Problem is I have around 24 group combination, so updating testNg.xml for every group seems not an option for me.

I am using JAVA , TestNg and Maven

**What am I missing here ?**

Test Code:

```
public class myTests extends Basetest {
    
    @Test(groups = {"group1","group2", "group3","regression", "smoke","sanity"})
    public void Test1() {
        System.out.println("          Test 1");
    }
    
    @Test(groups = {"group1","group2", "regression", "smoke","sanity"})
    public void Test2() {
        System.out.println("          Test 2");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"group1", "group3","regression", "smoke","sanity"})
    public void Test3() {
        System.out.println("          Test 3");
    }
    
    @Test(groups = {"group1","regression", "smoke","sanity"})
    public void Test4() {
        System.out.println("          Test 4");
    }
}
```

Base Test

```
public class Basetest {
    
    @BeforeMethod
    public void myConfig(){
        System.out.println("Before Method ");
    }
    

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(){
        System.out.println("After Method ");
    }

}
```

testNg xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>


      <class name="bik.Test.myTests"/>

    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Maven pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>bik</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.11.0</version>
             <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</testClassesDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: what is wrong?  group2,smoke will execute 4 coz its an OR condition.  What is it you expect to do?

Comment: @niharika_neo I am looking for AND condition ..
Expecting: when I will provide group2 and smoke it should execute only those test cases have both the group ..